# Python: list indices must be integers, not str?

Tags: python, list, csv

So I have code that looks like this:

```
with open(completeCSV, 'r') as csvfile:
    test = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for line in test:
        print(line)
        i = i + 1  # on the first line, i will equal 1
        count = line[0]
        if count == '1':
            for prof in proflist:  # vertex1=prof
                if line[1].lower() == proflist[prof]:
                    # if vertex1 is a professor, you want to keep the edge.
                    lines_to_keep.append(i)
                    break  # breaks and doesn't check the rest of profs
```

It basically reads in a CSV, and checks if a value from the csv equals another value from a list `proflist`.

I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/sskadamb/PycharmProjects/BetterDelimiter/filter.py", line 50, in 
>       if line[1].lower()==proflist[prof]:
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

is it because of the `proflist[prof]`? But I want to check all of the entries of 
`proflist` against `line[1]`. How would I do this, and what am I doing wrong? Can I not iterate though a list like that?

Comment: `prof` is an element of `proflist`, not an index

Comment: I see.. thanks. so then could I do `if line[1]==prof`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prof` is an element of `proflist`, not an index.

Substitute

```
if line[1].lower()==proflist[prof]:
```

with

```
if line[1].lower() == prof:
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Will be accepting... in 8 min  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for prof in proflist:  #vertex1=prof
        if line[1].lower()==proflist[prof]:
```

Prof is an iterator, no need to access it from the list again!

```
if line[1].lower() == prof:
```

Is what I think you had intended.

Answer (score 2):

What @mevius said seems true -- `prof` is a string, but misses the point:

```
for prof in proflist:  #vertex1=prof
        if line[1].lower()==proflist[prof]:
```

That code is a bit insane: you already iterate thru `proflist` with the `for` so that each entry in the list gets assigned to `prof` in the loop.

So I think you want just:

```
for prof in proflist:  #vertex1=prof
        if line[1].lower()==prof:
```

Where it is correct to have the `prof` as string and no `int(prof)` is actually needed anywhere.